# Sending data from JavaScript to PHP Without Client

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am attempting to create a logging type tool which will send data via JavaScript to PHP (possibly AJAX or something similar), however when it is sent, the Client stops using resources to process the data.

So in my mind, I would like the application to do the following:

1. JavaScript already on website initializes when user loads and imports another JavaScript file
2. Loaded JavaScript file gets some data (IP and Page)
3. Information is passed to a PHP script which does some correlation and WHOIS lookups, then sends it to a database for storage

In a perfect world, I would like this whole logging tool (or whatever you want to call it) to take 0ms to load, execute, and store data.  Well, that isn't quite possible, so I would *like* to find a way where data can be sent from JavaScript to PHP and have the load of that script running on my server, rather than the user's workstation or the web application which the end-user would visit.

Then again, I could be going crazy and AJAX already does this (or I am just asking for a method that is completely impossible).

Any ideas?  Is this even worth chasing around?

Comment: `"have the load of that script running on my server"` - Any part of this operation that's in PHP would be running on your server.  It's not really clear to me what the problem is here.

Comment: Well, to be honest I am not sure there is a problem.  
I set something up really quick and looked in the "Network" tab within Chrome's developer mode and saw that the PHP script is being loaded.  More of a curiosity question.

Comment: Well, if you're making a request to a page, then the network tab will show a request to that page.  I suspect you may be misunderstanding something, causing some confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of when you want to log such details of a user and only using a server is using php sockets, though they are hard to understand.

Javascript is a client-side language so it is not possible to run on the server-side.